# Best way of sorting hexadecimal numbers inside the QTableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I want to know the best way of sorting hexadecimal numbers inside the QTableWidget.

Currently what i do is convert all the hexadecimal values then sort it (ascending/descending). But my problem is since i did convert it to decimal. The values shown in table is in decimal. I want to sort hexadecimal without changing the value shown in table

Here is my current implementation:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QTableWidget

class NumericData(QTableWidgetItem):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.data(Qt.UserRole) < other.data(Qt.UserRole))

class Window(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__(4, 2)
        for column, values in enumerate((
            ('ABCD', '1DCA', 'BD23', 'FFFFFFFF'),
            (1,2,3,4)
            )):
            for row, value in enumerate(values):
                if column == 0:
                    value = str(int(value, 16))
                else:
                    value = str(value)
                item = NumericData(value)
                item.setData(Qt.UserRole, value)
                self.setItem(row, column, item)
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.sortItems(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)
```

Here is the sample table

```
|--Values--|
|ABCD      |
|1BCD      |
|DEC1      |
|123       |
|2105      |
|AAAAAAAA  |
```

Comment: What is the input, a string that represents the hexadecimal `'ABCD'` or a hexadecimal numerical value `ABCD`?

Comment: I don't get your question but `'ABCD'` is a hexadecimal value. what i want is to sort `'ABCD'`, `'1DCA'`, `'BD23'`, `'FFFFFFFF'`. if your asking for the decimal value of `'ABCD'` here is the converted value _43981_

Comment: 'ABCD' is not a hexadecimal, it is a string that represents a hexadecimal value. A hexadecimal is a way to express a number in base 16, for example: 0xABCD is a hexadecimal value, but 'ABCD' is a string that represents that numeric value.

Comment: yes it represents a hexadecimal value. what i want is to sort all the strings the represents hexadecimal values (ascending/descending)

Comment: Check edit above. that's the actual table shown. I want to sort that table without changing it's value shown

Comment: What i did is convert those string that represents hex value to decimal value. then sort it. but the problem is the data shown in table also changes since i convert it to decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to use a new role just to save the conversion since if the user changes the value you would have to recalculate that value, you can only pass in the role Qt::DisplayRole.

Considering this I have implemented the following example:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class HexDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(parent)
        editor.setMaximum(2147483647)
        editor.setMinimum(-2147483647 - 1)
        editor.setDisplayIntegerBase(16)
        fnt = editor.font()
        fnt.setCapitalization(QtGui.QFont.AllUppercase)
        editor.setFont(fnt)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.setValue(int(index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole), 16))

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        value = ('{:x}'.format(editor.value())).upper()
        model.setData(index, value, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)


class NumericData(QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return int(self.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole), 16) < int(
            other.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole), 16
        )


class Window(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__(4, 2)
        delegate = HexDelegate(self)
        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)
        data = ("ABCD", "1DCA", "BD23", "FFFF"), (1, 2, 3, 4)
        for row, values in enumerate(zip(*data)):
            for col, value in enumerate(values):
                it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                it.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, value)
                self.setItem(row, col, it)
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.sortItems(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm. But currently don't know where and when to use Display Role and User Role. Can you suggest any reference on this? Thanks in advanced